# Crontab - How to determine current active processes started by cron

Tags: linux, unix, cron, aix

We have a very sensitive application which heavily makes use of crontab and we would like to track of how many processes started by crontab are still running.

In short, we have a limit of 300 cron jobs in 'queuedefs' and we want to make sure that we are not reaching it.

Sincerely,
Dumb Admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you a list of processes whose parent is crond:

```
ps h --ppid $(pgrep crond)
```

Comment: I ended using this solution. The script checks every execution the crond ID and uses to list its children. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the PID of `crond` varies on each invocation.  So, how about this?

```
for pid in  $(ps -ef | grep -i crond | awk '{print $2}') ; do
  ps -ef | grep -vi crond | awk -v ppid=${pid} '{if ($3 == ppid) print $0}'
done | wc -l
```

This'll print out a count of all processes that have been started by a process called `crond`.